# Ace editor: Adding new folding file in the pre packed Ace src folder

Tags: ace-editor, code-folding

How/where should I place the new folding rule file in the pre packed Ace src pack?

Have tried adding 'folding' folder inside src folder and adding the file, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In  packed mode you should add folding to your mode file and wrap in define call, similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/21f7fa46ece12f8c425a5563784b3bf3fe84117d/src/mode-json.js#L109